# How to add Items in jcarousel ? in C#

Tags: c#, jquery, html, jcarousel

I would like to add Items in jcarousel using c# Webmethod + jquery Ajax

for that i made something like this :

my Html is like :

```
<div>
            <ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango" style="float: left">
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Jquery code for jcarousel and Ajax Method is like this :

```
 $("#mycarousel").empty();
        var element =jQuery('#mycarousel');
        $.ajax({
            url: "Home.aspx/GetProjectData",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: "{}",
            async: false,
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.d != null) {
                    //$.each(response.d, function (i, response) {
                    $("#mycarousel").html('response.d');
                    element.jcarousel(
                       {
                           pager: true,
                           visible: 6
                       });
                }
                else {

                }
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
            }
        });
```

and webmethod is like this :

```
 [WebMethod]
        public static List<string> GetProjectData()
        {
           // here i have 3 list in returnvalue
            foreach (var item in returnvalue)
            {
                var classvalue = item.Soid + "|"
                           + item.ProjectTitle + "|"
                           + item.Role + "|"
                           + item.StartDate + "|"
                           + item.EndDate + "|"
                           + item.Location.Country + "|"
                           + item.Location.State + "|"
                           + item.Location.City + "|";
                string Template = "<li><img src='../Images/DefaultPhotoMale.png' class='"+ classvalue + "' width='40' height='40' alt='image'/></li>";
                list.Add(Template);
            }
            return list;

        }
```

but problem is , i am not able to images in jcarousel , i only see white box,  i am not able to seee images inside, why ?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but wouldn't you need to append the elements sort of like this:

```
var listItem = $(response.d); //I'm guessing reponse.d is your returned li
element.append(listItem);
```

Comment: ah then you should try taking off the quotes from around the response.d (I thought it was only returning one li - didn't read the question properly!) also does the image exist, view the source and try browse to the image src

Comment: ok, i created new question is here  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15092909/how-to-write-ajax-method-to-fill-the-jcarousel